# AOSP Android.mk compile only one tool

Tags: android, compilation, android-source

In AOSP i want to compile one tool adb which located in system/core/adb.

I do not want to wait until the entire project is compiled to check one tool.

When I compile the entire project, the file is in this directory (out/host/linux-x86/bin/adb)

So how can i compile only adb (host tool)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make out/host/linux-x86/bin/adb